# Finding App Architecture using android API

Tags: android

Suppose we can use getPackageInfo in Package Manager in android and get any installed app's versionCode and all.
So can we find the architecture or the app? Like it's arm-v7a or arm64

I'll be very helpful to you.
Thank you

Comment: An app may support one or several CPU architectures. Most apps support all CPU architectures, because most apps do not contain native code.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question for "Java custom string encryption from a paragraph or set of strings", and would like to help because I've done something similar in c#.

I noticed that one of the largest reasons for that question being closed is because you were lacking in certain details that would help us determine what you needed.

This is an example of mine:

```
public static string Trans(string data) {
  data = ToBinary(ConvertToByteArray(data));
  string[] Adata = data.Split();
  string output = "";
  foreach(string word in Adata) {
    int count = 0;
    bool counting1s = false;
    count = 0;
    output = "";
    foreach(var ch in word) {
      if (ch == '0' && counting1s) {
        counting1s = false;
        if (count > 0) {
          output += bit1[count - 1];
          count = 0;
        }
      }
      if (ch == '1' && !counting1s) {
        counting1s = true;
        if (count > 0) {
          output += bit0[count - 1];
          count = 0;
        }
      }
      count++;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      output += (counting1s ? bit1 : bit0)[count - 1];
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

I could help you with making something in Java if youd like.